# Getting a url that always points to my dynamic ip address

Tags: ssh, dyndns, dynamic-ip

For work im sharing my computer at home with a colleague who can connect to it over ssh.But the problem is that i have a dynamic ip address, so i have to tell him what it is everytime.
I have heard of DynDNS which gives a url which always points to my ip.But i dont think they offer a free service anymore. 
Are there any other free alternatives to DynDNS that i can use for getting a url that always points to my latest ip address ?

Comment: D-link has a free DynDNS compatible service: https://www.dlinkddns.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but for home use it looks like no ip will work for you.

http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/managed_dns_compare.html

Comment: Even for pro use. I never had any problem with them for 60+ IPs. DynDNS gave me problems sometimes. Never tested any other.